# Implementing Data-tier Application using SQLServer 2008 and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: database, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I am in the process of converting an existing database to Data Tier Application. Visual studio 2010 provides a wizard feature to convert existing database to data tier application. In some of my stored procedures I am using msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail which raises the following error:

```
[dbo].[MyProcedure](StoredProcedure) - Depends on object '[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]' which does not exist in this database
```

So, for Data-tier Application are we not allowed to use built in stored procedures or have I missed something from the instructions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the context is wrong. I'm not positive but you could try added the database name in front of your call: [msdb].[dbo].[sp_send_dbmail]

Comment: I did think of that, but that is not the issue. Here is the body of the stored procedure:BEGIN
    EXEC msdb.dbo.SP_SEND_DBMAIL 
    @Profile_name='Test',
    @recipients= @email_recipients,
    @subject = @email_subject,
    @body_format = @email_body_format,
    @body = @email_body,
    @File_attachments = @file_attachments
END;

Comment: @user495402 Have you tried right clicking your project, select "Add Database Reference", and adding a reference to msdb?

Comment: So, while playing with this new method I found a solution, probably not the best way but works. So, I commented the stored proc that was not working, imported and as you mentioned added the reference and it seem to be working fine.